# s3cmd flagging CSS with wrong MIME type

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, circleci, s3cmd

I'm running automated builds on CircleCI of a react app.  And a step involves running `npm run build` and then copying to an S3 bucket to host builds.   What I'm seeing is that s3cmd is copying `*.css` files to my S3 bucket with the wrong MIME type (`text/plain`) and that when served up this is causing the web application to not work.

I'm running s3cmd version 2.0.2 both locally on my mac (homebrew) and on CircleCI (running inside of a nodejs container, installed via installing pip, setuptools, and installing s3cmd via `sudo python setup.py install`).

When running locally on my mac, I deploy my app like this:

`s3cmd put --recursive -P dist/* s3://$BUCKET`

On CircleCI -- I run the exact same command.   I have also tried the `--guess-mime-type` option which seems to have no effect.

The way I determine the MIME type is wrong is like this:

`$ s3cmd info s3://$BUCKET/$DEPLOY/static/css/main.a0a90112.css | grep MIME
   MIME type: text/plain`

When I run the same command after having deployed from my local machine, I get a CSS MIME type.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Follow-up -- I still have no idea why s3cmd is doing this, and it seems like buggy behavior, but it can be fixed manually by following up with `s3cmd modify "s3://$BUCKET/$SUBDIR/static/css/*.css" --mime-type="text/css"`

Comment: This sounds like the long-standing s3cmd bug with guessing the wrong MIME type via python-magic: <https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/198> <https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/376> <https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/643>. Does adding `--no-mime-magic` help?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits your comment solved my issue, I was dealing with it for the last two days, thank you so much. Please post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem with `s3cmd rsync` (not `s3cmd put` as in the question) setting files with extension `.css` as mime type type `text/plain`. Thanks to the comment above and in it's linked issues, this fixed it:

```
s3cmd sync --no-mime-magic --guess-mime-type ...
```

Comment: Thanks @devstopfix helped me a lot. The S3CMD config file can also be updated to have this change too.

I am using S4CMD however, and so far I don't see they have the same flag available, weird considering they've duplicated S3CMD and just extended it.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
s3 put ...
```

You can upload all your files excluding css with

```
--guess-mime-type --no-mime-magic --exclude "*.css"
```

And then you upload only css with forced mime-type

```
-m "text/css" --exclude "*" --include "*.css"
```